# Qt command error when nmake the odbc files

Tags: c++, qt, command-line, odbc

I'm new for C++ and Qt.

Recently, I was learning Qt with MS SQl, but I met a problem when compiling the odbc files.

Firstly I run qmake and it goes well. But when I use `nmake`, the following errors happened:

```
module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
```

[image]

Comment: This means you are mixing a 64 bit build with a 32 bit one. Make sure you configure and build from the same Visual Studio 32 or 64 bit command prompt.

Comment: I tried almost all comand tools include the one in qt, vs2015 x86,x64 command prompt, and cross tools as well. But none of them works.

Comment: You will have to clean build between tries. Did you build Qt itself from source?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to c++ and Qt. How to clean build between tries? And what means build qt itself from source? Do you mean qmake in odbc folder?

Comment: If you tried one time with the wrong command prompt then tried again on the same build folder you build folder would have been broken by the bad try.

Comment: ***And what means build qt itself from source?*** If you don't know what this means you probably downloaded a binary release of Qt and not the source code. Did you download the 32 bit version or the 64 bit version of Qt?

Comment: Yes, my qt is 32-bit version. Is this means I need to use a 32 bit command tool to build the file?

Comment: ***Is this means I need to use a 32 bit command tool to build the file?*** Yes. Use the VS2015 x86 Native Tools Command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered similar problem just today.

**Same as you**,

> I tried almost all comand tools include the one in qt, vs2015 x86,x64 
>       command prompt, and cross tools as well. But none of them works.

**I solved the problem by the following**:

1. Deleted the whole project and its folder completely.
2. Created the project anew.
3. Made sure `%PATH%` variable, aside from irrelevant paths, contained *only* path to *proper Qt build*. In my case `%PATH%` contained `'C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin'`. By *proper* i mean, of course, a Qt build that was built using the same compiler I was trying to compile with.
4. Then I ran `VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`.
5. Switched to the project folder.
6. Then i did `qmake` and then `nmake` and it was all OK.

**I think the problem was that**, as [drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm) suggested,

> If you tried one time with the wrong command prompt then tried again on the same build folder you build folder would have been broken by the bad try.

and therefore,

> You will have to clean build between tries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm) and [Herman Nurlygayanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6280807/herman-nurlygayanov), the problem is finally solved.

Here is some experience I get from this problem:

1. The version of Qt creator whether **32-bit** or **64-bit** should be made sure before all these stuff by checking the `About Qt creator`. It is important to choose the right version of command prompt before compiling.
2. Besides, If a **32-bit** command prompt is used, then `vcvars32.bat` should be executed. As for **64-bit** version, `vcvarsall.bat` should be executed. They are located in `%dir of you vs%/vc` and `%dir of you vs/vc/bin` respectively.
3. If any error happened during one compiling, another **`qmake`** must be executed in next attemption.